# Plotting a data frame in R

Tags: r, graph, dataframe

I have this data frame and I'd like to know if there's a way to plot this using the ggplot2 library (or anything that works). The first row has a bunch of zip codes and the second row contains weather data (temperature in this case) associated with the corresponding zip code. I want to create a graph (bar/plot) with the zip codes on the x axis and the temperature values on the y axis but I don't know how to do it.

```
     V1   V2
1  20904 82.9
2  20905 80.1
3  20906 84.6
4  20907 84.6
5  20908 88.0
6  20910 84.6
7  20911 84.6
8  20912 86.1
9  20913 86.1
10 20914 80.7
11 20915 84.6
```

Comment: Try `library(ggplot2); d1 <- as.data.frame(t(df1)); colnames(d1) <- c('zipcode', 'temp');ggplot(d1, aes(x=zipcode, y=temp)) +geom_bar(stat='identity')`

Comment: @akrun Probably should have mentioned my data frame is stored in  ZipGraph: `ZipGraph <- as.data.frame(ZipGraph) 
ZipGraph`

Comment: If the object `ZipGraph` is already a matrix.  then `d1 <- as.data.frame(t(ZipGraph))` and the rest as above

Comment: @akrun Just gives me a black rectangle. No graphs. Can you look at my edits on the post. On the second time running the code, my output looked like that instead.

Comment: Have you changed the column names as in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also can do a simple barplot:

```
ydf <- ZipGraph

barplot(ydf[2,],names.arg = ydf[1,],col=rainbow(ncol(ydf)),
        xlab="zipcode",ylab="Temperature",cex.axis = .8,cex.names = .7)
```

Edit: Or you can do

```
ylims=c(0,max(ydf[,2])*1.2)
y1=barplot(ydf[,2],col=rainbow(nrow(ydf)),xaxt="n",ylim=ylims,
        xlab="zipcode",ylab="Temperature",cex.axis = .8)
axis(1, at=y1,labels=ydf[,1],las=2,cex.axis= .6)
```

Comment: On the second time running the code, my output looked a lot different. How does that change the row and column ordering on the graph?
Running the code as is gives me: `Error in barplot.default(ydf[2, ], names.arg = ydf[1, ], col = rainbow(ncol(ydf)),  : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix`

Comment: That's because you transposed the data. Try `ydf=t(ZipGraph)`  or `barplot(ydf[,2],names.arg = ydf[,2],col=rainbow(ncol(ydf)),
        xlab="zipcode",ylab="Temperature",cex.axis = .8,cex.names = .7)`. Any should work!

Comment: @ Robert  Looks great. One little error though, the zipcodes don't show up on the x axis. The temperature values do. And the y axis only shows tickmarks till 80. Is there a way to increase this to about 100 because my temperatures are in the 84-85 range?

Comment: Update: i fixed the zipcode not showing up on the x axis issue by changing `names.arg = ydf[,1]`. Still haven't figured out how to increase the range values.